# How to add NOT NULL columns?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

I am starting to use database-projects and struggling with simple tasks. If I would like to add a new column which is `NOT NULL`, how can I make it work if there is already data in the table?

I used to write diff-scripts, in such a case I would have written something like:

```
-- ... ADD COLUMN X ... 
-- insert data into x
-- ... ALTER COLUMN X NOT NULL
```

How would I need to handle such cases with a database-project?

Thx for any tipps
sl3dg3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found finally two possible ways. In a nutshell:

- Use a default-constraint (as suggested by Rain)
- Fill the data in the post-deployment script, drop the default-constraint
- After deployment, remove the default-constraint from the source

Or

- Backup the table's data in the pre-deployment script into a temporary table, delete data from the target table
- In the post-deployment script, move the data back into the target table, including the new data for the new NOT NULL - column, drop the table

Found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/49bf2a88-d80d-4a9f-970e-728bd530332e/

Or here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bahill/archive/2009/03/30/managing-data-motion-during-your-deployments-part-1.aspx

Both means extra work, I was hoping for more support from the framework for such common cases. But at least it can be done like that.

Comment: what if the target table is referenced by many other tables? deleting the data will be headache! as you have either to migrate all related tables data, or to suppress the foreign key constraints of other tables before deleting the data from the first table.

Answer (score 5):

You could also, instead of specifying a DEFAULT value for the column, from the Publish DB Dialog; Go into Advanced->Advanced Deployment Options and check the "Generate Smart Defaults" box.

From the description in VS:
Generate Smart Defaults: Automatically provides a default value when updating a table that contains data with a column that does not allow null values.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a not null column by providing some default value while creating the column.

Comment: You mean a default-constraint? And then do what with it, delete it in a second step? I would like to not use default-values in general since I consider them as evil. It is up to the application to write appropriate default values.